# mysql delete from same table based on select statement

Tags: mysql, recursion, sql-delete

I am really wrapped around the axle.
I am trying to delete some records from a table.
This doesn't work ...

```
delete from table where id in (select id from table where ...
```

... because I get the dreaded ...

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000) at line 1: You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause
```

... so I went for the temp table option ...

```
create temporary table idTemp (idt bigint(20) unsigned); insert into idTemp select id from table where [...]; delete from table where id in (select idt from idTemp); drop table idTemp;
```

... which only works when run as root.  If I run as the desired user I get ACCESS DENIED no matter how much privilege I give the user.
I tried adding CREATE, DROP, INSERT, DELETE, SELECT and still get ACCESS DENIED.
But when I try to give the user CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES access I get ...

```
ERROR 1144 (42000): Illegal GRANT/REVOKE command
```

I have MySQL version 5.5.14 running on Linux.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also phrase your original query as a `join`:

```
DELETE t
FROM table t
JOIN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE ...) todelete ON t.id = todelete.id
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql>

```js
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```